# PNG image on ios app showing black

Tags: ios

We have a png image that seems to be showing all black in our ios app and we are wondering if there is possibly something wrong with the image

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2982102/Temp/cq5dam.thumbnail.140.100.png

Comment: Post some example code or explain how you are using the image.

Answer (score 0):

On that image, the background is transparent, so if you have a black background, it's going to all look black. Try changing the background color to white.